# Preventing org-mode from translating a comment as an itemize environment

Tags: latex, org-mode, listings

I have an `org-mode` document which I want to export as a PDF. I'm using the LaTeX listings package to generate nicely formatted code listings, which look like this in org:

```
#+BEGIN_LaTeX
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Java]
    /** Comment comment comment
     * 
     * blah blah blah
     * 
     * @return comment
     */
    public void foo() {
        return;
    }
\end{lstlisting}
#+END_LaTeX
```

The Javadoc comment there is being translated by org as a LaTeX `itemize` environment, like this:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Java]
    /** Comment comment comment
\begin{itemize}
\item 
\item blah blah blah
\item 
\item @return comment
\end{itemize}
     */
    public void foo() {
        return;
    }
\end{lstlisting}
```

How can I prevent this from happening and keep the Javadoc as I originally wrote it? If I use `#+BEGIN_SRC` rather than `#+BEGIN_LaTeX` what I get back is a `verbatim` environment, but I want to stick with listings rather than `verbatim` or minted since I've already made the effort to put together a nice set of stylings for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are ultimately wanting is a [literal example](http://orgmode.org/manual/Literal-examples.html).  Essentially you want the code to be exported, but fontified.  You need to tell `org-mode` to use listings (or minted) upon export.  This can be done in your *.emacs* file:

```lisp
;; tell org to use listings with colors                                                     
(setq org-export-latex-listings t)
(add-to-list 'org-export-latex-packages-alist '("" "listings"))
(add-to-list 'org-export-latex-packages-alist '("" "color"))
```

Also, with this you don't need to specify the `listings` package in a header argument to your document.  Now, source code blocks will be exported in the appropriate `lstlistings` environment:

```
#+begin_src java                                                                
  /** Comment comment comment                                                   
   *                                                                            
   * blah blah blah                                                             
   * @return comment                                                            
   */                                                                           
  public void foo() {                                                           
    return;                                                                   
  }                                                                             
#+end_src
```

gets exported to LaTeX as

```
\lstset{language=java}
\begin{lstlisting}
/** Comment comment comment
 *
 * blah blah blah
 * @return comment
 */
public void foo() {
    return;
}
\end{lstlisting}
```

I'm not quite sure why, when you use the `#+begin_latex`...`#+end_latex` block in your example, that things are getting parsed weirdly.  In principle, one would like whatever is in the LaTeX block to be passed as-is to the *.tex* file.

Comment: LaTeX blocks do not entirely ignore Org Mode syntax.  It acts as a sort of hybrid block.  I can't remember the exact details of what is and isn't converted but I believe bold/underline/italics are still treated using the usual Org Mode escapes.  It would seem lists are as well (The lines that export incorrectly are all valid list elements in Org)